# Declare Global Variable, Initialize within Method

Tags: c++, global-variables, static-libraries, thrift

I am creating a thrift client, which has a bunch of overhead: a `TSocket`, a `TBufferedTransport`, and a `TBinaryProtocol`. Usually it is created like this

**Example Thrift Client**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    shared_ptr<TTransport> mysocket(new TSocket("localhost", 9090));
    shared_ptr<TTransport> mytransport(new TBufferedTransport(mysocket));
    shared_ptr<TProtocol> myprotocol(new TBinaryProtocol(mytransport));
    TestServiceClient client(myprotocol);

    try {
        mytransport->open();
        client.testmethod();  //and you can call server methods like so
        mytransport->close();
    }catch (TException &tx) {
        printf("ERROR: %s\n", tx.what());
    }
}
```

However, for my client, I want it in the form of a static library. Thus, there is no main method, and I created `init()` and `exit()` methods to open and close `mytransport`. That also meant I had to make `mysocket`, `mytransport`, `myprotocol`, and `client` all global variables, but I also want to set `mysocket` to an ip other than "localhost", which means initializing `mysocket` inside a method. Any ideas?

PS. Also, does anybody know how I can call `init()` and `exit()` automatically when the static library is opened and closed? [SOLVED]

edit: I forgot to mention that I can't initialize  `mysocket` until I know the correct ip, so I don't think I can declare mysocket as a global variable anyways

Comment: There are probably better ways to do this, but you can use a static local variable.  For instance, `Socket& get(){ static Socket mysocket = initstuff(); return mysocket; }`.  The first time the function is called, `mysocket` is created and returned.  On further calls, it is simply returned.

Comment: After reading the edit, I'm not sure you're still looking for another solution or just adding some additional information.  If you can't initialize until the user inputs something, then you have the entry point right there in that input function.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the question more thoroughly, I think this may be more along the lines of what you are looking for:

mylib.h

```
class libClosure{
  public:
  libClosure();
  ~libClosure();
};
```

mylib.cpp

```
#include "mylib.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

libClosure::libClosure(){ cout << "call open()" << endl;}
libClosure::~libClosure(){ cout << "call close()" << endl;}

libClosure __lc;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mylib.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  cout << "client.testmethod()" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

output

```
call open()
client.testmethod()
call close()
```

Constructing an initializing object within an implementation file is a common way to achieve exactly what you're looking for.  Essentially, the constructor for `class libClosure` becomes your entry point, and the destructor for `class libClosure` becomes your exit point.

The reason this works is because all implementation files for the headers must construct their global variables before `main()` is run.  You can't guarantee that one implementation file will be constructed/destructed before another, but you know that all objects in implementation files *must* be constructed before the `main()` at some point, and destructed after the `main()` at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving it myself. Even though using static local variables like Aggieboy suggested seems perfectly valid, I think this is a little simpler:

**barebones version**

```
shared_ptr<TTransport> mysocket(createTSocket());

TSocket* createTSocket() {
    //init stuff goes here, for example
    string ip = "localhost"
    int port = 9090

    return new TSocket(ip,port)
}
```

**the full code (well, most of it)**

```
class ThriftProxy {
public:
    ThriftProxy() :
        trans(createTSocket()),
        proto(new TBinaryProtocol(trans)),
        client(proto)
    {
        trans->open();
    }

    TSocket* createTSocket() {
        //default: ip = "localhost", port = 9090
        string ip = "localhost";
        int port = 9090;

                    //get ip and port from a text file

        return new TSocket(ip, port);
    }

    ~ThriftProxy()
    {
        trans->close();
    }

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<TSocket> trans;
    boost::shared_ptr<TProtocol> proto;
public:
    XtkServiceClient client;
};
```